# Ffmpeg pipe stream glitch

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, video-processing

I want to process ffmpeg raw video stream, and I can't understand why this code produces glitches. What's wrong?

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo - | 
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1980x1080 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 24 -i - -an out.avi
```

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of glitches are you experiencing?

Comment: [like that](http://rghost.ru/6FrXYgfcM/image.png)

Comment: I think your problem lies in the size you are specifying: 1980x1080 != 1920x1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `rawvideo` streams, you have to have the correct size set, so you need to change your invocation of `ffmpeg` to:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo - | 
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 24 -i - -an out.avi
```

This is assuming that your `in.mp4` file is a Full HD file.